# iOS 7 BarTintColor

Tags: user-interface, ios7, uinavigationbar, bartintcolor

Have any one else noticed in iOS7, the translucent navigation bar only shows color underneath if barTintColor is set to default?

I tried setting barTintColor to various different colors, but anything that is below the navigation bar is displayed a a black blur. Whereas if the barTintColor is set to default, all the elements display correctly underneath.

Is there a way to force it to show the correct colors?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use background color instead of tint color.

self.navigationController.navigationBar.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];

If you are using tint color it changes only barbutton background color change.

Comment: Hi Abha, using background color will lose the translucency of the bar. I want to keep the translucency of the navigation bar.

Answer (score 0):

In MyTabBarController in the storyboard select the color tint. You will change the button active color background. No idea for the inactive one.